# Export ArcMap Symbology to table, text or other format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, convert

In ArcMap how can I export a symbology style to table or text format such as .csv?

[image: Symbology dialog with highlighted desired export area]

Comment: I am looking for the reverse methode. How to import labels from Excel in the Symbology?

Answer (score 2):

I found a kludge courtesy of *Sephe Fox* [on GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/122368), **extract the definition from a legend graphic**:

> add a legend to your map document containing only that layer. Then,
>   right click on the legend and convert to graphics. You will have to
>   ungroup the legend and also each of the symbology types, but then you
>   can select the boxes with just the text, by dragging a rectangle
>   around all of them, and copy. You can then paste them as text into
>   Excel, and each will be on a new row.

After you have everything in rows use Excel's "*Data >> Text to Columns >> Delimiter '`(`'*" to split  `Label (value)` into separate fields and then Search & Replace `)` with nothing.

It works but is cumbersome and not what I'd call a solution. Still if you're in bind this might let you keep going.

---

Another approach is **mine the map's [Service Definition Draft](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/createmapsddraft.htm)** (*File >> Share as service >> Save as service definition file >> Choose 'No connection'*) , unzip the archive, locate the `.msd` file, unzip that, find `layer_name.xml`, then in Excel [Open as XML Table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-XML-in-Excel-f11faa7e-63ae-4166-b3ac-c9e9752a7d80#bmrepeat) and scan for columns `FieldName, String, Label`.

[image: Excel XML table screenshot]

(Note the RGB columns which might be useful for the related [Saving a ArcMap layers RGB values into the attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/124401/saving-a-arcmap-layers-rgb-values-into-the-attribute-table) question.)

There is an arcpy snippet in [Getting layers from .msd using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16083/getting-layers-from-msd-using-arcpy) for getting to the layer file, and a more fully developed script at [Using ArcPy to get layer symbology?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1466/using-arcpy-to-get-layer-symbology/). I've lost track of the original Q/A that led me to the idea of using a service definition.